# Marshal 3GB byte[] to IntPtr C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, out-of-memory, cloud, marshalling

I need to send a stream from a video file over to an unmanaged C++ DLL however is I try to copy the bytes to IntPtr vie Marshal.AllocHGlobal I get a System.OutOfMemoryException.

The data needs to be processed in the C++ dll with FFMPEG no thanks to Microsoft's broken FFMpegInterop for Windows 10.

Thanks all.

Comment: You shouldn't want to read the complete 3GB into the memory. What about a memorymappedfile?

Comment: Hi  Jeroen van Langen, thanks for the reply, I will need to look into a MemoryMappedFile as I am not very familiar with it. I was thinking maybe I can copy and process 1GB at a time in a loop to get around this also, thanks for the suggestion.